# Empty State Flutter

Tags: flutter

Actualmente tengo un gif de precarga de datos y quiero que si después de 10 segundos no recibe datos, se quite el gif de precarga de datos y se muestre el Empty State que tengo pero no se como hacerlo, porque actualmente se me queda todo el rato en el gif de precarga de datos porque está esperando a que reciba datos.

Tengo el siguiente código. En _con.blogs es donde almaceno la información que recibo de mi API

```
_con.blogs.length == 0
          ? EventBlogLoaderWidget()
          : Container(
              child: _con.blogs.length == 0
                  ? Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Lottie.asset('assets/animations/empty_state.json'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder
```

Comment: sube tu código para que te podamos ayudar.¿De donde estas esperando datos?

Comment: Acabo de modificar la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: yo creo que mas bien donde cargas tus datos es donde pudieras meter una validación, puedes poner un timeout a tu petición y regresar tu objeto vacío en caso de exceder el tiempo

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero, pero no se como hacer que pasado 10 segundos, cambie al Empty State y no se vuelva a repetir la comprobación a no ser que vuelva a cargar la vista.

Comment: En la llamada a tu API http.get("url",headers: {}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10))..catchError((e) {
      return {"statusCode": 501, "body": "$e"};
    });;

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días esto debe de funcionar:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Llamatimer());
}

class Llamatimer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LlamatimerState createState() => _LlamatimerState();
}

class _LlamatimerState extends State<Llamatimer> {
  List<int> _listaimages = [];//LA LISTA ESTA VACÍA

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: _crearLista(),
    );
  }

  Widget _crearLista() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
          AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.amber, title: Text('llamada timer')),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _listaimages.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final imagen = _listaimages[index];
            const twentyMillis = const Duration(seconds: 5);
            if (_listaimages.length == null) {  //SI NO HAY DATOS EN LA LISTA ESPERA  CINCO SEGUNDOS
              Timer(twentyMillis, () {
                Container(child: Text('No se encuentran listas de datos'));
              });
            } else {
              return FadeInImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=$imagen'),
                  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/jar-loading.gif'));
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```